# Pygame - How do I make an image stop moving?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make my image move when called upon. It keeps moving my image to the right and doesn't stop. How do I make the image stop incrementing forever? Ty

```
def move(self, x):
        self.rect.x += x
```

Comment: Can you post _all_ your code, specially the code inside the main game loop? It seems like the `move` method is being called over and over...

Comment: When is it supposed to stop? When you stop pressing a key? When it hits a wall? After *X* seconds? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `if` somewhere to make it stop moving:

```
while True:
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pygame.K_up in pressed:
        move(self, x)
```

[Some info about keys.](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html)